# how to display data in datagrid without knowing table structure in ASP .net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, datagrid

I want to display all table data in my page. But i don't know the table structure

So how to **display data from SQL DB in datagrid without knowing table structure** in asp .net?

if it possible in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

```
 <asp:DataGrid id="ItemsGrid"
           AutoGenerateColumns="true"
           runat="server"
           DataSourceID="YourDataSource">
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

the attribute `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` generates the structure automatically on the basis of DataSource.